# JavaMail - Invalid HELO name

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I used to run a server app that sends an e-mails each 2 hours, but sometimes i get the error below:

```
Não foi possível enviar a mensagem.
Mensagem: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Jan 07, 2013 1:00:32 PM job_hidrojato.comunicacao.email.Email run
SEVERE: null
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
at job_hidrojato.comunicacao.email.Email.run(Email.java:186)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I've already tried to explicitly define the mail.smtp.localhost using the code below, where "HADES" is the hostname of my server, but it didn't work.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "HADES");
```

The error log gerenated after this change is the same, so I think that the problem isn't the hostname parameter. I already read the links below but again, didn't work, so I'm running out of alternatives to solve this problem, and any help would be appreciated :)

[Invalid HELO name in JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934373/invalid-helo-name-in-javamail)

[550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542616/550-access-denied-invalid-helo-name)

Comment: Is `HADES` the name of the SMTP (mail) server or the server trying to access the mail server ?

Comment: Hi Peter, HADES is the server trying to access the mail server.

Comment: Can the mail server resolve `HADES`?

Comment: That's my question too, i have no access to mail server and its administrator is absent at this moment, is there a way to do some test, or explicity set the IP instead of hosname?
FYI: I've tried to telnet on port 25 and it was successful.

Comment: No I can't think if a way to test, try using the FQDN for you HADES server .

Comment: Hi Peter, I've asked the network staff for help. They did some tests and told me it was a routing problem, that is solved right now. My app is working again. Thank you very much for your attention, it helped me to obtain a better knowledge about how the client-server communication works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up [RFC2811](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) section 4.1.1.1 it says (emphasis mine):

> These commands are used to identify the SMTP client to the SMTP
>   server.  The argument field contains the **fully-qualified domain name**
>   of the SMTP client if one is available.  In situations in which the
>   SMTP client system does not have a meaningful domain name (e.g., when
>   its address is dynamically allocated and no reverse mapping record is
>   available), the client **SHOULD send an address literal** (see section
>   4.1.3), optionally followed by information that will help to identify
>   the client system.

The name `HADES` is not a fully qualified domainname (which is hostname+domain, eg `www.example.com`, some definitions of FQDN also require a dot a the end (ie `www.example.com.` but I am unsure if that is required by SMTP). If you don't have a FQDN, you should use an address literal (see section 4.1.3 Address Literals), which basically is the IP address.

Also be sure that your SMTP server is not actively restricting access to unknown or unauthenticated hosts.

Comment: Hi Mark, as I said above, it was a routing problem identified by the network staff, already solved, so my app works again. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Always nice servers giving an error cause that is not the actual reason. Good to hear it was solved